# Kubuntu 20.04 ping trouble: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: kubuntu, libraries, ping

I just upgraded from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Everything went fine except when I ping an address in local session where I get this message:

```
ping: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In root session it's ok, `ping` works.

I tried to install `libnettle6` but it has been replaced by `libnettle7`.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111635/discussion-on-question-by-skyline-kubuntu-20-04-ping-trouble-libnettle-so-6-ca).

Answer (score 1):

In this case it was probably an issue with a dependency list of version `20190709-3` of `iputils-ping` package. Some dependency seems to be missing in the list.

The error in question was resolved by installing a `nettle-bin` package which apparently contains some of the needed files.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nettle-bin
```